# Time Complexity Analysis On For Loops

Tags: c++, time-complexity, big-o, complexity-theory

I am confused on analyzing the time complexity on a 'for loop'. Do the contents in the loop not counted like example:

```
for(i=0;i<=n;i++){
   statement
       .
       .
}
```

Wouldnt i=0 excute once, i<=n excute (n+1), and i++ execute n times. So why is the time complexity only counted (n+1) times for the 'for loop'? shouln't the contents inside be summed like:
1+n+1+n? just confused since my prof summed them up but the book only counted (n+1).

Comment: There is a difference between asymptotic complexity and number of executed instructions, the former omits multiplicative constants.

Comment: Asymptotic complexity is a set of possible functions. So a function that takes `n` instructions and one that takes `2n+1` instructions both fall into the set `O(n)`, which consists of all (at most) asymptotically linear functions. You'll see some (imo poorly written) textbooks write things like `2n+1 = O(n)`, which is sloppy notation when they actually meant `2n+1 ∈ O(n)`

Comment: To make it clear: It is the `O` notation, which removes the added constant and the multiplicative factor. The number of instructions are `2n+2`. The benefit of the `O(n)` is that it is more independent on the machine running it. Some processors for example can increase a memory cell in one instruction, some have to load into a register, increase, and store back. With the definition of the `O` notation, one can concentrate on describing the complexity of the algorithm in a general way.

Answer (score 4):

What you are asking is what the asymptotic notation is all about.

Say that you have a program like the following

```
for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    print("hello")
}
```

that compiles into a fictional pseudocode machine language in which each of the numbered items below are single machine instructions:

```
 1. let i -> 0 
 2. if (i >= n) goto 6. 
 3. print "hello" 
 4. increment i 
 5. goto 2. 
 6. ... (continue with the rest of the program)
```

then for a given *n* the total number instructions that will run when executing the loop is 4*n* + 1, one instruction to initialize *i* and four instructions for the body of the loop which executes *n* times.

Big-O et. al. is about how a function like f(*n*) = 4*n* + 1 behaves as *n* grows. The definition of Big-O is basically that for large *n*'s some function f(*n*) is O(g(*n*)) if there exists a constant *k* such that

> f(*n*) ≤ *k* g(*n*).

In this case if g(*n*) = *n* we can see that, for all values of *n* greater than zero, f(*n*) ≤ 5 g(*n*) so 5 is a valid *k* and we can say that f(*n*) is O(*n*).

This is the point of Big-O: it lets us talk about how functions grow ignoring additive and multiplicative constants.