# O(n/2) search in linked list

Tags: c++

I'm supposed to make a search method for a linked list that has time complexity O(n/2). What would this look like? I heard that saying O(n/2) is the same as O(n). So is it just a search of all of the linked list's items? Or is there a specific sorting algorithm that would help me do this?

Comment: Assuming uniformly distributed keys and a target key that is actually in the list, the average number of steps to get a match for the standard linear search through a linked list of n items is n/2. Not O(n/2), just n/2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O(n/2) is indeed equivalent to O(n) so an O(n/2) search is just a linear search i.e. iterate over the list and test each item until you find the one you are looking for.

If you are confused why O(n) and O(n/2) are equivalent, see [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71787995/1413244).

Comment: Hey so sorry for asking another question, it's just because of the downvotes I can't post on stack overflow again, but I saw code in which using a template an attribute is dereferenced twice, written like this: T** list, what exactly does this mean? It's just a standard template<class T> class

Comment: @sebramirez There's no dereference in  `T** list;` because that's a declaration not an expression. However, `T* list;` would make `list` a pointer to `T`, so `T** list;` makes `list` a pointer to a pointer to `T` (aka a double pointer).

Comment: T** means pointer to a pointer to a T. You need that if you want to use a pointer to refer to another pointer. Say you want to write a function that is going to allocate a T and fill in a T* that the user passes in with what it allocated. The signature of that function cannot take just a pointer because the pointer they pass in is passed by value. If you assign the one you allocated to the pointer passed in that is just replacing a local variable in the function. If however the signature of the function is a T** then you can do what you want to.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys that's been very helpful, just one last thing because I'm kind of a noob, is there a place I can ask stupid questions at? I don't really wanna destroy my stack overflow account but I think I'm gonna have many stupid or basic questions and don't know where else to ask them, thanks for all the help and bearing with me

Comment: gamedev.net, although obviously being focused on gamedev, has good forums, including beginner friendly ones.